# How would I get the encrypted string to appear in chunks?

Tags: python, encryption

The program reads the file the user wants to encrypt:

```
with open(encryptSpecialFileName,mode= "r",encoding= "UTF-8") as myFile:
        fileToSpecialEncrypt = myFile.read().splitlines()
```

The program then sets up the list for the encrypted message.

```
    encryptedSpecialFile = []
    for string in fileToSpecialEncrypt:
        s1 = ""
        for char in string:
```

(Here it calls the function that encrypts the file)

```
encryptedSpecialChar = encryptSpecialCharacter(char, offset)
```

Then the encrypted characters are added to the list.

```
 s1 = s1 + encryptedSpecialChar      
 encryptedSpecialFile.append(s1)
```

How would I split this string into chunks of five to make decryption more difficult?

Comment: 1. Print characters 0 through 4. 2. Print characters 5 through 9. 3. Print characters 10 through 14. 4. Print characters 15 through 19. I'm sure you get the picture?

Comment: Also, standard disclaimer: keep in mind that any encryption algorithms you come up with are probably easy to break, even if *you* can't break them. So don't use them for anything serious.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python

Comment: BTW, it's slightly more efficient to collect your strings into a list and then use the string `.join()` method to combine all the strings into one string. Also, `string` is not a good variable name since that's the name of a standard module.

Answer (score 1):

To split the encrypted string into groups of five, we may collect first 5 characters into a string and then append the string into a list. Then we repeat the process until the entire encrypted string is exhausted.

```
encryptedString = "Thisistheencryptedtexttobesplitintogroupsoffive."
encryptedChunks = []

chunk = ""
for ch in encryptedString:
    if len(chunk)==5:
        encryptedChunks.append(chunk)
        chunk = ch
    else:
        chunk += ch
encryptedChunks.append(chunk)

print encryptedChunks
```

Here, the variable `encryptedString` contains the string returned from your function `encryptSpecialCharacter(char, offset)`.